# SQL/DB design: multi-column foreign key with mixed NULL/NOT NULL treated as mandatory or optional?

Tags: sql, database-design, foreign-keys

In DB design/SQL is it theoretically possible to declare something like that:

```
CREATE TABLE Groups
(
  round_id    INTEGER  NOT NULL,
  ordinal_nbr SMALLINT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (round_id, ordinal_nbr),
  FOREIGN KEY (round_id) REFERENCES Rounds (id) /* irrelevant, just a reference to another table's ID */
)

CREATE TABLE Games
(
  id               INTEGER  NOT NULL IDENTITY,
  round_id         INTEGER  NOT NULL,          /* !!! */
  ordinal_nbr      SMALLINT NULL,              /* !!! */
  scheduled_tipoff DATETIME NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (round_id, ordinal_nbr) REFERENCES Groups (round_id, ordinal_nbr) /* multi-column FK round_id NOT NULL, ordinal_nbr NULL */
```

)

Now the question:

Since this has to be considered rather a programming mistake, what is the best thing to adjust for such scenarios: treat such FK's as mandatory or treat them as optional?

What would be a logical policy here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I'm thinking about it it seems to make more sense to consider the whole FK rather optional. As soon as one piece of information is missing, whether intended or not, the whole FK depends on the column(s) whose value hasn't been set YET.

After all, the NULL destroys obligation. It makes more sense to me than the other way around.

Comment: it makes less sense to make the whole constraint optional but in effect that is what many DBMSs will do. The SQL standard defines three different optional behaviours for this situation: FULL, PARTIAL and SIMPLE. SIMPLE is the default but some DBMSs will have different behaviour and some support the other options as well. The best way to be sure is to try it out and see what happens with your DBMS. Again, my strong advice would be to make both non-nullable and change your code accordingly.

Comment: I'm writing a plugin that handles this situation, so I have no influence on the incoming "code". Again, I just have to account for such situations and adjust accordingly.

Comment: not sure what you mean by a plugin but if you have no control over the code then I see no way to ensure you get the right result or not, so your question seems to be unanswerable. In any case the results may be different depending the DBMS, which is something you have not specified.

Comment: I process other people's DB designs and I need to define how to act on such a situation. I generate code from that, but in programming languages there's no equivalent for a half-defined reference (the OO analogy).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a general answer to that.  In the existing data, are there any null values in games.ordinal_nbr?  There might be code out there that expects to be able to put a null in there, so you have check all the code that uses that table.  Even more fun is different databases handle that in different ways.  Some consider "null = null" to be true while others consider any comparison operator false if either side is null even if both are.

Comment: Do not all modern databases support some sort is null operator by now?

Comment: Any comparison with =, <>, ... is always NULL AFAIK (untested), you have to use the IS operator when comparing NULLs (for sure). IS always returns either FALSE or TRUE, but never NULL.

Comment: This is a hypothetical question. As such it doesn't matter whether my data has this information or not.

Comment: One I've hit where null=null is SQLServer.  There's an option you have to set whether to use standard null comparisons or not.  I seem to also remember some issue between Oracle and PostgreSQL with unique index on null values but that might have been Oracle's thing with consider an empty string a null.

Comment: Yes, I understand the question was hypothetical but the answer is there is no general answer.  It all depends on the assumptions in the code that's using the tables.

Answer (score 0):

Why does it have to be a mistake?

Consider a Adults table and a Offspring table that references it.

(mis-stated previously) *edit:*

What if there were Offspring that you did know the parents of? Just ignore that they exist.

*edit:*

This is a real example I just encountered recently:

I am basing my database against a de-normalized source where I have no control over the data. A key referencing the owners table should be required logically. Running a query I came across an owner name that was:

`'UNKOWN OWNER'`

Hmm, that could floated around for a long time and it was only chance that I caught it. I run aggregate queries against the owner table where things like that will give me incorrect results. The designers of that database traded in the 'enormous complexity' of dealing with nulls by hiding it with their own brand of null.

If the value was blank or null it would raised an error immediately and I could changed the table in the beginning  of the design. Also, in aggregate queries nulls fall out of joins so you do not have incorrect results. And when I want them I just `left join` the tables.

Comment: But those are two very different cases: No kids; Not known if they have kids. Surely you wouldn't represent BOTH cases with a null? You'll get some incorrect results if you do.

Comment: Yes, I agree but without nulls allowed in the foreign key how could you represent it properly?

Comment: By recording only the facts that are known (ie the closed world assumption). If an adult doesn't have offspring then there would be no rows for that adult in the Offspring table.

Comment: I would never model adults & offspring as separate tables - they're all `PEOPLE`, and there'd be a relationship table to associate mother/father to child because it's hierarchical in nature.  You could get more specific (grand parents, cousins) if you wanted...

Comment: @OMG Ponies: My assumption in this case is that the "Offspring" table is exactly what you are calling the "relationship" table. Whether it is or not, my advice to avoid a nullable foreign key would still stand.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: forgive the analogy. In a real system there are always possibilities of orphan data. Without nulls you either redefine your own null or pretend it does not exist.

Comment: nate c: "What if there were Offspring that you did know the parents of?" Then there would be no rows in the table that relates a child to its parents (see previous answer).

Comment: There's nothing wrong with optional foreign keys.  The problem is having a multiple element foreign key where some elements are required and some are not.  The behavior of this is not clear and works differently in different SQL databases.

Comment: I still can't imagine how the SQL code would look like and thus I wonder how this answer relates to my question... the described would look to be like a "broken FK". @nate c: Mind to add the DDL for your half-nullable FK?

Comment: @JOTN: You seem to imply the questionable behaviour of SQL is avoided if BOTH columns are nullable - it isn't. The problem remains the same. Nullable foreign keys in SQL are effectively a broken "feature" for most practical purposes.

Comment: @nate c: Your new example of someone using a substitute "unknown" value in place of null doesn't seem relevant here. No one else suggested doing anything like that. I simply suggested NOT using nullable foreign keys.

Comment: What do you do if you model games (table) that you usually know the arena (table) of where the game is played (FK Games -> Arenas), but there are certain games where you don't know the arena at all? Sounds like a nullable FK to me...

Comment: @Kawu : Just don't have a row in a table that relates Games to Arenas. No nullable FK required.

Comment: Extra? I don't like the term "join table" anyway. There is only one sort of table.

Answer (score 0):

Nullable foreign keys in SQL have plenty of disadvantages. From a semantic modelling perspective it is unlikely to make sense. For example suppose the intended meaning of a null ordinal_nbr is that that attribute is unknown. In that case SQL may not evaluate the other attribute and won't return an error even if there is no matching row for the *known* value of round_id (YMMV depending on DBMS and other options).

I suggest you redesign it so as to eliminate all nullable foreign keys.

Comment: Note as the question was put I did not intend this into a discussion about whether NULLs on FKs are a good or a bad thing or whether the semantics make sense or not. The question is purely technical: is the NULL column stronger or is the NOT NULL column stronger? It is just a hypothetical question. My software has to be prepared for such situations, whether intentionally or accidentally created - I DON'T CARE.

Answer (score 0):

Create a single Field in your Groups table to act as the primary key and join on that..

You have an administrative nightmare here.

`NULL<>NULL`!!!!!

If X is Unknown and Y is Unknown can you say X=Y?
Depending on the you DB\ Configuration the Join may even fail.. an in my option the fact that any DB allows `NUll=NULL` to return `True` is a Mistake.